# UIImageView image appearing twice

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiimageview

I have a `UIImageView` in my `tableview` cell which extends `UITableViewCell`. It creates the `imageview` during initialization, and I set the `imageView.image` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. But, since the size of image is smaller than `imageView`, the image is appearing twice, as shown below: [image]

Why is this happening? I know there is one way that I resize the `UIImageView`, but the cell is also being used somewhere else where I set different image. Please tell me the reason and solution for this. Thanks!

Edit: Updated `cellForRowAtIndexPath` code which is still not working.

```
    var cell: AutocomplterViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(AutocomplterViewCell.reuseIdentifier) as! AutocomplterViewCell
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = AutocomplterViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: AutocomplterViewCell.reuseIdentifier)
    }
    if tableView == self.recentsTableView {
        let recentArr: [RecentSearch]? = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().getRecentSearches()
        let item: RecentSearch = recentArr![indexPath.row]
        cell.setTitle(item.title)
        cell.setAddress(item.subAddress)
        cell.setImageIcon("Clock")
    } else {
        let item: GMSAutocompletePrediction! = mapTasks.allResults[indexPath.row]
        let address: String? = item.attributedFullText.string
        if address != nil {
            let addressArr = address!.componentsSeparatedByString(",")
            let title: String = addressArr[0]
            let tempTitle = title+", "
            let full: String = address!.length > title.length+3 ? address!.substringFromIndex(tempTitle.endIndex) : address!
            cell.setTitle(title)
            cell.setAddress(full)
            cell.setImageIcon("GrayPin")
        }
    }
    return cell
```

and the AutoCompleterViewCell class:

```
import Foundation

class AutocomplterViewCell: UITableViewCell {

class var reuseIdentifier: String {
    return NSStringFromClass(AutocomplterViewCell)
}

static let cellHeight: CGFloat = 60.0
let topMargin: CGFloat = 10.0
let bottomMargin: CGFloat = 10.0
let betweenMargin: CGFloat = 5.0
let leftMargin: CGFloat = 10.0
let rightMargin: CGFloat = 10.0
let fontSizeLarge: CGFloat = 14.0
let fontSizeSmall: CGFloat = 11.0
let borderWidth: CGFloat = 1.0

var contentHeight: CGFloat {
    return AutocomplterViewCell.cellHeight - topMargin - bottomMargin
}

var predictionTitle = UILabel()
var predictionFull = UILabel()
var icon = UIImageView()
var borderLine = UIView()

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    self.setupView()
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func setupView() {
    let iconHeight: CGFloat = 20
    let titleHeight = fontSizeLarge + 4
    let fullAddressHeight = fontSizeSmall + 4

    // icon
    self.contentView.addSubview(self.icon)
    self.icon.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
        make.left.equalTo(leftMargin)
        make.centerY.equalTo(self.snp_centerY)
        make.width.equalTo(iconHeight)
        make.height.equalTo(iconHeight)
    }
    self.icon.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit

    // title
    self.contentView.addSubview(self.predictionTitle)
    self.predictionTitle.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
        make.left.equalTo(self.icon.snp_right).offset(leftMargin)
        make.top.equalTo(topMargin)
        make.right.equalTo(-rightMargin)
        make.height.equalTo(titleHeight)
    }
    self.predictionTitle.textColor = UIColor.blackColorText()
    self.predictionTitle.font = UIFont.ixiRegularFontOfSize(self.fontSizeLarge)

    // full address
    self.contentView.addSubview(self.predictionFull)
    self.predictionFull.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
        make.left.equalTo(self.icon.snp_right).offset(leftMargin)
        make.top.equalTo(predictionTitle.snp_bottom).offset(betweenMargin)
        make.right.equalTo(-rightMargin)
        make.height.equalTo(fullAddressHeight)
    }
    self.predictionFull.textColor = UIColor.grayColorText()
    self.predictionFull.font = UIFont.ixiRegularFontOfSize(self.fontSizeSmall)

    // border
    self.contentView.addSubview(self.borderLine)
    self.borderLine.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
        make.left.equalTo(leftMargin)
        make.top.equalTo(predictionFull.snp_bottom).offset(bottomMargin)
        make.right.equalTo(-rightMargin)
        make.height.equalTo(borderWidth)
    }
    self.borderLine.backgroundColor = UIColor.defaultBorderColor()
}

func setTitle(title: String?) {
    self.predictionTitle.text = ""
    if title != nil {
        self.predictionTitle.text = title
    }
}

func setAddress(address: String?) {
    self.predictionFull.text = ""
    if address != nil {
        self.predictionFull.text = address
    }
}

func setImageIcon(img: String?) {
    self.icon.image = UIImage(named: img!)
}
}
```

Comment: add Tableview delegate method code.

Comment: You might also want to add the `setImageIcon` method.

Comment: You should dequeue your cells, not create them.

Comment: I did that, please see the edit. It is still not working @Mundi

Comment: @Justa added the setImageIcon method as well..

Answer (score 0):

This actually reminds me of a problem I had. UITableViewCell by default has a property called `imageView`, according to your post  ''It creates the **imageview** during initialization, and I set the **imageView**.image'' it seems like you added your own **imageview** to it, two variables. Are you adding the image to BOTH image views?.

Can you post your AutocomplterViewCell class to confirm?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! No, I am not doing that. There is default setImage method of cell (I think), but I am not using that.. Please see the edit for autocompleterviewcell class @julian-j-tejera ..